# passar valor js a outra página no action form

Tags: php, javascript

Olá,
eu possuo um simples formulário com alguns campos, os quais eu envio os valores para outra página via form action:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="novapagina.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
```

eu desejaria enviar uma variável js conjuntamente aos campos do formulário, para tal, tentei:

```
<?php 

 $variavel_php ="<script>document.write(variavel_java_script)</script>";
        ?>
```

e no form action:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"   enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="novapagina.php?id=<?php    echo     $variavel_php;   ?>" method="post" >
```

portanto o valor da variavel na página que recebe é a string: `<script>document.write(variavel_java_script)</script>`

preciso passar o valor inteiro contido na variável js.

Usando jquery, pelo que vi teria de refazer todo o form, não é minha intenção,

1)existe uma forma de passar (forçar) o valor inteiro a variavel php e abrí-lo em um nova pagina??

2)existe um método de passar a variável js no form action??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode passar valores do javascript para o PHP, a não ser que faça isso com Ajax. Mas podemos fazer isso de uma forma mais simples.

Crie um campo do tipo hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="variavel_js" id="variavel_js" />
```

Agora atribua o valor que você tem no seu js.

```
document.getElementById("variavel_js").value = variavel_java_script;
```

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado!! resolveu!

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é utilizar localstorage, é muito simples, basta executar o comando abaixo via javascript:

```
// Na página do formulário
localStorage.setItem("variavel_js", "Valor da sua variável");

// Na página que gostaria de resgatar o valor, pode ser em qualquer uma desde que o valor foi setado:
var variavel_js = localStorage.getItem("variavel_js"); // Vai ser igual a "Valor da sua variável"
```

No site da w3schools tem uma ótima documentação sobre este recurso, veja no [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Este recurso é suportado nos seguintes browsers:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: perfeito!! realizei um teste aqui e foi satisfatório